# Solve Inequality with ceiling function.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality, ceiling-and-floor-functions

1. Motivation:

   > Let $n,e,d$ be integers greater thant 2, such that $e\mid n-1$ and
   >   $d\mid n-1$.  For $i=1,2,3,4,5$, define 
   >   $$L_i=L_i(n,e,d)=a_{i1}n+a_{i2}e+a_{i3}d,$$ and  $$k=\lceil
   >  \frac{L_1}{L_2} \rceil.$$ Suppose $$L_3 k^2 + L_4 k + L_5<0.$$ Denote
   >   $\delta=e-d$, i.e. $d=e+\delta$. Find out $G_i=G_i(n,e)$, $i=1,2$,
   >   such that $G_1 < \delta < G_2$.
2. My trying:
   If $k=\frac{L_1}{L_2}$, then I would solve the problem as follows.

1) Multiplying both sides by $L_2^2$, $L_3 k^2 + L_4 k + L_5<0$ if and only if $L_3L_1^2+L_4L_1L_2+L_5L_2^2<0$

2) Replace $d$ with $e+\delta$. We have four functions $H_i=H_i(n,e)$, $i=1,2,3,4$ such that 
$$H_1 \delta^3+ H_2 \delta^2 + H_3 \delta + H_4 < 0.$$

3) Solve the cubic inquality to obtain $G_1$ and $G_2$.

However it does not work in the first step if there exists ceiling function. Of course, by the ceiling function we have $$\frac{L_1}{L_2}\le k < \frac{L_1}{L_2}+1.$$
Denote $LHS=L_3 k^2 + L_4 k + L_5$. For simplicity, assume $L_2>0$, then 
$P_1\le LHS < P_2,$
where $$P_1=\frac{L_3L_1^2+L_4L_1L_2+L_5L_2^2}{L_2^2},$$ and $$P_2=\frac{L_3(L_1^2+2L_1L_2+L_2^2)+L_4(L_1L_2+L_2^2)+L_5L_2^2}{L_2^2}.$$
I am not sure if the sufficient and necessary condition of $LHS<0$ is $P2<=0$. However my question is a bit complicated.

3.Question

> Let $n,e,d$ be integers greater thant 2, such that $e\mid n-1$ and
>   $d\mid n-1$.  Define 
>   $$L_1=L_1(n,d)=dn+d+n-1,$$
>   $$L_2=L_2(n,e,d)=e(d+n-1)$$
>   and  $$k=\lceil \frac{L_1}{L_2} \rceil.$$ What is the sufficient and necessary condition of $$L_1 k^2 -(2L_2+L_1) k + (e+1)L_2-d(2en+e-3)<0,$$
>   having the form $G_1 < \delta < G_2$, where $\delta=e-d$ and $G_i=G_i(n,e)$, $i=1,2$?